# How to get analysisID in sonar

Tags: sonarqube

GET api/qualitygates/project_status call to sonar requires analysisId.
I am not able to figure out that how to get the same.
http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/qualitygates/project_status

In report-task.txt  i have only this information created

```
projectKey=org.cidemo.multispring:parent
serverUrl=http://localhost:9000
dashboardUrl=http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/org.cidemo.multispring:parent
ceTaskId=AVI5GTgLuMgLdhRswoyi
ceTaskUrl=http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVI5GTgLuMgLdhRswoyi
```

And no analysisid. There is nothing mentioned in the doc shared by you  as how to get this id. In my env i want to  check if code passed the quality-gate, and fail the build  if it dont passes.

I do not want to use this using Jenkins.I have created a pre-commit hook in which i am calling a sonar run when developer tries to commit and  if code do not pass the quality gate ,commit must be aborted.Let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `analysisId` is the ID of a snapshot. Normally, you never see this in the Web interface. The main place where you will find it is in the `<work_dir>/report-task.txt` file that is generated at the end of an analysis in your file system.

In fact, the main (at least original) purpose of this `api/qualitygates/project_status` WS introduced in SQ 5.3 is to be used when you want to break the build after the report of an analysis has been submitted to the server. You can find the comprehensive explanation on the ["Breaking the CI Build" documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Breaking+the+CI+Build).

Comment: In report-task.txt  i have only this information created

Comment: analysis ID can be found in the JSON returned by /api/ce/task. I updated the "Breaking the CI Build" documentation page which was not clear about that.